# GIT: Better method of setting up fresh repo

Tags: git, repository, init

With creating a fresh git repo, I am wanting to know what is best practice. Ether creating the git repo locally and pushed, or remotely and pulled. 
.

**Method 1**

*Local machine (inside whatever project folder)*

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin <server-repo-url>
git push --all origin
```

Or is it better practice to set up the repo on the server and then pull from it onto your local machine?

**Method 2**

*Remote server*

```
mkdir myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git --bare init
```

Or does it even matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't particularly matter.  Git is designed to allow the equivalent repositories to be shared between clients and servers.  So long as your client(s) are fully configured to work with a repository on the server, they're both great.

Comment: Got it, thanks @La-comadreja

Some reason I have always thought of the repo on the server to be different somehow. Makes perfect sense though now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter.  Either repo can be discarded once both are up and running.